# polling Log in service

Tags: android

Hi i created a service successfully

```
public class Securityservice extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("Service","I Am Security Service Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

I got that Log message in onCreate() ..

but the problem is i got that message only once at the time of service created

i need to keep print the log Untill i destroyed the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service is an BackGround task which runs until you stop which contains its own life cycle.
Where as Thread is also a new task which runs until you stop or end of the code, which contains its own life cycle.

While creating the Service onCreate method will call only one time.. 
I think you have some confusion between **Loop** and **Thread**..

it is must to start a loop (for or while) to print that log continuously ..

or you can use this type of recursive method

```
 public void onCreate() {
 super.onCreate();
 doLog() 
 }

void doLog(){
  Log.d("Service","I Am Security Service Created");
doLog();
}
```

Comment: Thanks now my doubt cleared but if i use this type of recursive method in oncreate().. when oncreate() functions calls it created a new service

Comment: yes, you will get this type of errors, because you are increasing the heap size of the program, you have to use code optimization for that..

Answer (score 1):

Start a thread and  loop it again and again

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               while (true) {
                   try {
                       Thread.sleep(10000);
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   // Your code
               }
           }                        
        }).start();
```